# 1980s Children's Picture Book About an Alien (Martian) Society

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, illustrated-story

I read this is in elementary school (in the US) between 1980-1985. It could have been published 10 or more years earlier. It was a large, rectangular paperback and thin. The book consisted of pages of Where's Waldo-styled illustrations (black ink on green backgrounds?) of an alien civilization.

The drawings were large - covering the whole page (usually in 2-page spreads) - and highly detailed. There were no "close-ups," only whole city or town scenes. I faintly recall a Logan's Run-styled dome city with interconnecting tubes that had trains running between them. There may have been cut-aways revealing the interiors of the buildings and vehicles. I also faintly recall pages that took place outside the city in a desolate landscape where the aliens wore spacesuits.

In terms of the aliens, they resembled classical "little green men" and were very humanoid (I seem to remember they reminded me of the drawings of Sea Monkeys like the below). Any thoughts?

[image]